# Migration from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services - Backlogs and git repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

We are trying to move existing backlogs(work-items) and codes in git repo from Azure DevOps server to services. Is there a tool out there to move these items with the capability to retain the history of work item and code merge/check-in?
Or if there is a way to do this using the Azure devops REST Api, please share it with me :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to migrate git repos and work items from Azure DevOps server to services, you can follow these steps to manually import a repo into an Azure DevOps Services repo with history:

1. Clone the source repo to a temporary folder on your computer using the `bare` option, as shown in the following command line example, and then navigate to the repo's folder. Note that when cloning using the `bare` option, the folder name includes the `.git` suffix.

   `git clone --bare https://github.com/contoso/old-contoso-repo.git
   cd old-contoso-repo.git`
2. Create a target repo in Azure DevOps Services.
3. Run the following command to copy the source repo to the target repo.

   `git push --mirror https://dev.azure.com/contoso-ltd/MyFirstProject/_git/new-contoso-repo`
4. If the source repository has LFS objects then fetch them, and copy them from the source repo to the target repo.

   `git lfs fetch origin --all
   git lfs push --all https://dev.azure.com/contoso-ltd/MyFirstProject/_git/new-contoso-repo`
5. Delete the temporary folder.

Reference link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#manually-import-a-repo

There is no default way to migrate work items with history. You would check the following tools:

- [vsts-work-item-migrator](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-work-item-migrator)
- [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility)

If you want to migrate all data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services, you would start from the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops